# External SATA enclosure for multiple disks

Tags: hard-disk, data-storage, drive-enclosure

I'm looking for an external SATA enclosure to host a minimum of 4 standard 3.5" form-factor SATA hard disks.

I currently have a 4-disk enclosure from Vantec that uses a SATA port multiplier but has a drawback that one port always reads as SMART disabled regadless of the disk and overall suffers from poor cooling.

My requirements:

- Minimum of 4 disk enclosure for 3.5" form-factor SATA disks
- Good cooling, ideally low vibration and not too loud
- eSATA data interface
- Not a rackmount solution.  This will sit on a desk or on the floor.
- Ideally can accommodate 6 GB/s SATA III disks at full bandwidth.
- Externally powered with a switch to turn it off
- Fairly easy install/removal of disks in the enclosure.

My use case is intermittent backup where the disks and enclosure are only on and spinning during the backups.

Comment: Question: do you have a controller that supports SATA port-multiplier?

Comment: @AdamComerford yes, my current enclosure uses a port-multipler and my system reports it as `ata6.15: Port Multiplier 1.2, 0x197b:0x0325 r0, 5 ports, feat 0x5/0xf`

Answer (score 4):

OK, so I have used an [older version](http://www.icydock.com/goods.php?id=201) of this product with success, but not had a chance to use their latest version.  My experience was good enough to make a general recommendation.  [Icy Dock](http://www.icydock.com/) now offers a 4 disk enclosure, with lots of nice options (including adjustable fan speeds, dust filters, drive trays) called [Black Vortex](http://www.icydock.com/goods_cat.php?id=146).

You need to have [port-multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_multiplier) support to use the eSATA interface and that is limited to SATA II speeds (3 GB/s).  I should note that I used USB personally on the Icy Dock, and FireWire 800 on an Drobo rather than eSATA - my experiments with eSATA drives have been poor (might just be my bad luck).

On that point, you will only get one channel's worth of SATA II bandwidth (3GB/s) with this approach. That is significantly less than a well performing USB 3.0 interface, especially when you consider that a single channel SATA II is limited to ~300MB/s thanks to [8b/10b encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding).  USB 3.0 will likely outperform eSATA here, so worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

The Mediasonic Probox looks like a good option for you. It can be found [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003X26VV4) It has support for esata and usb 3.0. It has fairly good cooling with a thermal sensor to automatically change the fan speed. It has a power switch and can give you 6 gigabytes per second which is the maximum you are going to find in a sata 3 disk. It also has 4 bay enclosoures and it is not a rackmount solution.

Comment: Have you utilized the Probox before? How loud is it?